# Would testicular cancer have been detected before?

Tags: testicles

It's been about 9 months since I have had ultrasound, MRI, and blood tests performed on me AFTER I was diagnosed with hydrocele and varicocele in my scrotum by the emergency center. I, of course, went to the urologist, and they're the one's who ordered all of these tests on me. They said my varicocele wasn't significant enough to be uncommon. They found nothing abnormal after all these tests. So, I just let it go.

The symptoms of dull ache and pain persisted, which became aggravated when I did physical activity, especially anything involving my legs.

About 2 months ago, I played very intense basketball after a while, and it's been on elevated pain since then. I scheduled a trip to the urologist.

I feel a scrotal mass or lump on one of my testicles. I looked it up, and it's possible that it's a lot of things.

My question is, is it possible that I have testicular cancer if all those tests were performed on me 9 months ago? Would they not have caught it back then?